# use a 32 byte initialisation vector in pycrypto

Tags: python-2.7, encryption, aes, pycrypto

I am trying to decrypt a text using python with pycrypto.
But I get: ValueError: IV must be 16 bytes long

However my iv is 32 bytes long and I cant change that.
My key is also 32 bytes in size
Is there a way to do this with pycrypto? I could find anything in the docs.

```
import Crypto.Cipher.AES as AES
a=0x0
i='68fe3a4cf921122eda3df6c7d5458497'
print(i)
plain="encrypted text"
print(plain)
length = 16 - (len(plain) % 16)
plain += chr(length)*length
print(plain)
plaintext=""

for a in range(0, 0xffffff):
    s="6af6f9fae1ab621c2aba5f80ea4"+hex(a)[2:].zfill(5)
    print(s)
    cipher = AES.new(key=s, mode=AES.MODE_CBC, IV=i)
    text=cipher.decrypt(plain)
    if isinstance(text, unicode):    plaintext=text

print(plaintext)
```

Comment: What key/block size/mode are you using that permits a 256 bit IV?

Comment: Nowhere near enough information.  What algorithm are you using?  Is the key in hex?

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: https://pastebin.com/NrtFkYBf

Comment: `i` is a hex string & is likely supposed to be decoded to bytes `i.decode('hex')` which will give you the correct 16 byte length.